# Get rid of the Reversal badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, badges

I'm only asking this here, because the badge may have applications outside of Stack Overflow (for example, the main Stack Exchange Meta), but if it belongs on http://meta.stackexchange.com, all the better.

In the last few days, I've seen a growing, frustrating trend, of people answering egregiously bad, heavily-downvoted, off-topic, low-effort or homework questions.

Then someone will upvote the answer, because it *is* correct, even if they just did someone's homework, then another upvote will get added, then another, and then someone will comment "Here comes the reversal badge!"

Why?  Why should someone get a gold badge for *doing someone else's homework*?

Or the scenario that prompted me to ask, just now, was that the answer-giver to an oft-asked, easily-Googleable, minimal-effort question got a downvote, then another, then a third, and they commented, "No reason to down vote it ! How else can you get the https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal".

How, indeed!

I understand the badge originally existed for outstanding answers on poor questions, but with the trend SO has taken in recent years to clean up and remove poor questions ("broken windows"), so...

- Does the Reversal badge have a place on Stack Overflow anymore, especially if it just encourages badge hunters to intentionally answer seriously low-quality questions?
- Can badges be retired so that those have earned it can keep it, but it can't be earned anymore?

Comment: Playing devil's advocate but considering this has only been awarded 190 times on SO, is this that much of a problem?  The last one being awarded in October for a question asked in March - it doesn't seem that this is awarded enough to be a huge issue.

Comment: @bluefeet - I knew someone was going to ask that, thanks for asking!  Just because it's only been awarded 190 times clearly hasn't deterred people from trying, based on the comments I quoted.  If you make it available, people will try to unlock it.  It's probably as low as it is because the community is usually darn quick at cleaning up messes.  Why should a subset of the community be able to play games with upvotes to earn badges on lousy questions?

Comment: Happy to ask the _hard questions_!  But do you have any links to comments where this has been asked?  Or have you queries SEDE to see how often these comments pop-up?  I'm not disagreeing with your request, just trying to flesh out the extent of the issue. :)

Comment: @bluefeet - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27066795/334849; I'm looking through my history now to find a few from the other day.  I don't have enough experience with SEDE queries (and maybe I shouldn't be allowed in there, LOL), but I'd be curious to see some query results as well

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables (the serious part ...) Well, questions and answers are different things. Though I have to agree such an award mainly encourages the rep-whores answering the help vampires (and I dislike such of course) :-P ...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MW9QR.gif

Comment: @gnat Yup! Seen that very enlightening diagram before, that was exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: @bluefeet - one more comment:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26976647/334849; I know two comments isn't an epidemic, so still digging.

Comment: Can you get the badge if the question is closed?  Can it be taken away if the question is closed after you get it?

Comment: @Will: yes. no.

Comment: Agreed that this badge sends a mixed message. On one hand, there's a constant stream of "don't answer bad questions! don't feed the help vampires!" here on meta. And then there's a gold badge for answering bad questions. Badges are supposed to encourage good behavior, and I don't think this one does.

Comment: Aww, the rep-whores have detected this meta question, I've certainly seen over 10 upvotes here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Should be no, yes.

Comment: did you consider how Reversal "interplays" with recently introduced [Explainer -> Refiner -> Illuminator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240302/165773) badges? It feels like these somewhat clash: refinement badges encourage answerer to improve the question while Reversal makes answerer wish it sink down further...

Comment: @gnat - I didn't even know those were a thing.  Makes me wonder what else I've missed.

Comment: I think you missed because these were introduced only recently. Other than that, your analysis looks quite thorough

Comment: Another pro argument you could use is that reversal answers mostly end up being deleted. More info about this, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88709/the-lost-worlds-of-the-reversal-badge/197616#197616). Not sure if I agree retiring the badge, but something could be done to improve its effect upon the site.

Comment: This is an excellent idea. Remove that badge, please!

Comment: Personally, I think that http://stackoverflow.com/a/3905805/209139 *deserves* the badge.

Comment: I somewhat agree, but part of me says people will scrabble for *points* regardless. so even if you remove the badge, people won't change

Comment: I realize I'm late to the discussion on this. Just wanted to note that of the (at present) 232 times this has been awarded, 135 of the questions have been deleted. That's more than half. I really like @BenVoigt's suggestion to award it only for questions that later regain some +ve votes.

Comment: *Are* there actual badge hunters out there? What motivates them?

Comment: As [announced on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) we've retired Reversal _and_ implemented two variations on [Ben Voigt's idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277691/1438).

Comment: @JonEricson Neat!  I don't even remember making this post, but I like it!  Fun fact -- between the post date and implementation date, I've had two kids.

Answer (score 48):

Questions meeting the criteria for the reversal badge are not bad *of necessity*.  There do exist a small number of questions that are downvoted because of lack of understanding by the voter.  That wouldn't lead to a score of -5 or below, except for the existence of voting rings which the moderators tolerate despite the fact that they generally involve abuse of the rules[<sup>1</sup>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278092/please-no-more-cvpls-lets-have-club-moderators-instead).  Of course, there is a very strong correlation between -5 and questions that truly suck.

I've come across a few cases myself where the "common knowledge" is incorrect.  Most often that results in swarms of upvotes on incorrect answers, but I'm sure that sometimes it affects questions.

If we could find a way to make the Reversal badge only apply to giving great answers to questions which were misunderstood, it would make it exceptionally difficult to earn, which is not a problem -- it is after all a *gold* badge, and also stop people using it as an excuse to feed vampires.

The linked question bemoans the fact that the deletion of a question where a Reversal badge was earned makes it more difficult for them to earn a second.  I disagree that this is in any way a problem.  If a negatively scored question gets deleted even with a highly voted answer clarifying the situation, then it isn't misunderstood, it's bad.  Let's celebrate the way deletion gives demerits against future Reversal badges, by making it an explicit feature.

For example, the Reversal could require that the question stay open and undeleted for another 30 days, and there could be a 10k+ tool for viewing candidates.  It would be a good place for people hunting for "Refiner" badges, because this list would collect the on-topic but misunderstood questions.

How about this: Reversal is changed to require that the question have -5 score *when the answer is posted*, the answer gets +20, **and the question later (possibly with edits) reaches +5 score.**  These criteria should prevent it from ever being awarded for answering true garbage.

Comment: Good idea. I would even deem it sufficient for the question to come back to a positive (+0) total score after posting the answer.

Comment: Just consider one change to your proposal, it should be enough if the question reaches -5 up to a day after posting the answer, no need for it already having -5 then. Or should that also be a (mostly ineffectual) stand against FGITW? (Maybe I'm seeing that wrong, not that sure...)

Comment: I'm not so sure that seeing a question vote swing differential of +10 is likely.  Most questions that are downvoted beyond -2 seldom make it back up to 0, let alone anything positive beyond that...

Comment: @Makoto: Most questions that go down below -2 really are terrible.  This is supposed to be about the rare exception.

Comment: I suppose what should be done is to take a look at the questions on SO that have earned someone this badge and take a look at their average score.  There may be one or two that *have* broken positive, but my gut feeling is that the average score may hover around -2.

Comment: @Makoto: The low quality of "most of the questions that have earned someone the badge" is the reason people are talking about getting rid of it.  We need to raise the quality bar.

Comment: Yeah--I see questions go negative that aren't necessarily bad/easily searchable/etc. just maybe annoyingly n00bish (or they ask how to do something whose wisdom reasonable people disagree on, or asker can't state the problem precisely but gets the idea across, or they're initially useless but get fixed, or other things). I don't want to see things sunk too easily. "Gets back to +0" seems good to me.

Comment: (Looking at questions that made it from from -2 to positive could be an interesting exercise.)

Comment: I like this answer because it takes account of how excruciatingly annoying it is when people herd-vote a question down because they don't understand it.  Especially relevant in tumbleweed tags.

Comment: it still encourages people to answer rubbish, I think it's best to avoid it and perhaps offer people a badge for a posts that undergo a reversal from -5 to a positive value generally http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279285/can-we-retire-the-reversal-badge#comment904959_279285

Comment: A great big tip o' the hat to you! We [announced on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) we've retired Reversal _and_ implemented two variations on your idea!

Comment: @JonEricson: Very glad to see it worked out.

Answer (score 34):

### Update ×2: implemented June 18, 2019

[See announcement blog post.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/)

### Update: declined, August 19, 2016

Michael Stum has been investigating the potential implementation of a more enlightened version of this badge, along the lines described in Ben Voigt's answer and discussed further below in this one.

Unfortunately, calculating the score of Q&A at various points in time makes the proposed replacement criteria too expensive to implement. Performing these calculations in a query requires walking the entire votes table, consuming large amounts of memory for most sites; this would put undue strain on the system. Tracking data for these separately would add an unacceptable level of complexity.

It's a nice idea; I wish we could do it. But it's not going to be possible, now or in the foreseeable future.

---

### Original

I was kinda underwhelmed by this question discussion at first. I remember the discussion that originally suggested the Reversal badge (yes, way back in the User Voice days) - by the time [the badge rolled out](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/reversal-and-pundit-badges/), the terrible question that inspired it had already been deleted! Even then, it was pretty obvious that earning this badge was gonna be like winning the lottery - a nice reward, but not really sensible to play for.

...Then I saw [Ben Voigt's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277576/get-rid-of-the-reversal-badge/277691#277691):

> How about this: Reversal is changed to require that the question have -5 score *when the answer is posted*, the answer gets +20, **and the question later (possibly with edits) reaches +5 score.**  These criteria should prevent it from ever being awarded for answering true garbage.

That... Sounds really cool. Especially since those criteria dovetail nicely with [some other badges we recently rolled out](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/). I *had* to see what it would actually turn up...

Run this code snippet to see the results:

```html
<h2>Answers scoring >= 20 on questions scoring <= -5 when the answer was posted and now scoring >= 5</h2> 
<table><tr><th>Question Score</th><th>Answer Score</th><th>Answer Link</th><th>Answered</th><th>Current Reversal Badge</th></tr> 
<tr><td>31</td><td>40</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/17631035">Is there an opposite to display:none?</a></td><td>Jul 13 2013  2:22PM</td><td></td></tr>                                  
<tr><td>5</td><td>27</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/17425080">can't convert Symbol into String</a></td><td>Jul  2 2013 12:00PM</td><td></td></tr>                                        
<tr><td>89</td><td>168</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/14788468">How to install JDK on Ubuntu (Linux)?</a></td><td>Feb  9 2013  1:06PM</td><td></td></tr>                                 
<tr><td>17</td><td>24</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/14414488">Why 0 ** 0 equals 1 in python</a></td><td>Jan 19 2013 12:43PM</td><td></td></tr>                                          
<tr><td>69</td><td>145</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/12614698">What's the difference between MyISAM and InnoDB?</a></td><td>Sep 27 2012  5:33AM</td><td></td></tr>                      
<tr><td>7</td><td>48</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/11759800">Upload Android app to google play step by step...?</a></td><td>Aug  1 2012 12:57PM</td><td></td></tr>                      
<tr><td>14</td><td>23</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/11061352">How to get TimeZone from android mobile?</a></td><td>Jun 16 2012  6:25AM</td><td></td></tr>                               
<tr><td>5</td><td>25</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/10347205">Forecasting time series data</a></td><td>Apr 27 2012  8:20AM</td><td></td></tr>                                            
<tr><td>11</td><td>21</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/9737529">How to Remove BOM from an XML file in Java</a></td><td>Mar 16 2012 12:48PM</td><td></td></tr>                              
<tr><td>30</td><td>66</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/9679614">Run an exe from C# code</a></td><td>Mar 13 2012  7:00AM</td><td></td></tr>                                                 
<tr><td>53</td><td>80</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/8928888">How to make a whole 'div' clickable in html and css without javascript?</a></td><td>Jan 19 2012  3:41PM</td><td></td></tr> 
<tr><td>15</td><td>34</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/8882358">How to get the first element of the List or Set?</a></td><td>Jan 16 2012  3:41PM</td><td></td></tr>                        
<tr><td>10</td><td>26</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/8612289">Array of PHP Objects</a></td><td>Dec 23 2011  4:35AM</td><td></td></tr>                                                    
<tr><td>9</td><td>34</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/8188465">C++ warning C4018: '&lt;' : signed/unsigned mismatch</a></td><td>Nov 18 2011  8:07PM</td><td></td></tr>                     
<tr><td>10</td><td>26</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/7058885">UIAlertView easy way to tell if cancel button is selected</a></td><td>Aug 14 2011  6:42PM</td><td></td></tr>               
<tr><td>65</td><td>92</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/6413615">How to get last 4 character from a string in c#?</a></td><td>Jun 20 2011  3:25PM</td><td></td></tr>                        
<tr><td>18</td><td>53</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/6345011">Checking whether the string contains only a number value</a></td><td>Jun 14 2011  2:20PM</td><td></td></tr>                
<tr><td>21</td><td>21</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/4093822">How to generate an array with random values, without using a loop?</a></td><td>Nov  4 2010  4:08AM</td><td></td></tr>      
<tr><td>185</td><td>209</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/1047491">What is lexical scope?</a></td><td>Jun 26 2009  5:26AM</td><td></td></tr>                                                
<tr><td>11</td><td>29</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/639196">Different ways of writing the "if" statement</a></td><td>Mar 12 2009  3:32PM</td><td></td></tr>                             
<tr><td>112</td><td>131</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/224626">How do you make div elements display inline?</a></td><td>Oct 22 2008  6:09AM</td><td></td></tr>                           
<tr><td>22</td><td>24</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/179626">How can I convert VB6 code to C#?</a></td><td>Oct  7 2008  5:54PM</td><td></td></tr>                                        
<tr><td>20</td><td>20</td><td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/121002">Any other mainframers here?</a></td><td>Sep 23 2008  1:30PM</td><td></td></tr>                                              
</table>
```

23 answers would be eligible to earn a badge with these criteria. Notice that *none* of those answers have currently earned a Reversal badge... So this does seem like a fairly meaningful change to the criteria.

That said, this looks like a *really* hard badge to earn. What if we change the question score requirements a bit?

- -4/+4 would qualify **63** answers for badges (though one of them already qualified for a Reversal badge under the current rules before it got upvoted)
- -3/+3 would qualify **176** answers, 3 of which previously qualified for Reversal
- -2/+2 qualifies **455** answers, 7 with existing Reversal badges
- -1/+1 qualifies **1633** answers, 10 with existing Reversal badges

If you're curious, the full results for -1/+1 can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Shog9/d8145de494c0a2d49ec5

Comment: I was thinking 23 answers seems kinda light for a badge (even a gold badge), but I was thinking of twiddling the answer score variable instead. It's already quite an accomplishment to get +20 on an answer even without considering the history of the question. Going from -1 to +1 isn't much of a reversal.

Comment: Lowering the answer threshold makes this (already slow) query *really* slow in a hurry, @Jon - dropping it to 5 took over 11 seconds to run on SO. I also think it makes this badge less special - yes, a score of 20 is quite an accomplishment on its own, but salvaging a seemingly-doomed question with an answer that gets a score like that is really a step above. But the best reason not to bother tweaking the answer score? **It doesn't matter:** if we keep the question threshold at -5/+5, dropping the answer threshold to +5 only gives us 64 qualifying answers.

Comment: "-3/+3" rings a bell - it is at +3 when the magic of [keeping rep for deleted posts happen](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/ "'score of 3 or greater'"), meaning like score has reached a threshold considered reliably useful

Comment: -3 is also the threshold where 20K users can opt to immediately delete a closed post, @gnat. There's a certain symmetry there.

Comment: so, question progresses ("reverses") from a point where trusted users can immediately delete it, to the point where system considers it good enough to keep the rep even if it's eventually deleted. That sort of clicks doesn't it. And 176 answers to be awarded sounds about right, keeping (in)frequency of the badge about the same as now ([190](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal))

Comment: I'm not sure instantly doubling the number of awarded badges is such a good idea, so I'd go with -4/+4  Still, at both 3 and 4 it has about the right amount of scarcity that an elite gold badge ought to.

Comment: Also, 23 just became 22.  Yay for Mjolnir!  (The C4018 question)

Comment: @BenVoigt there would be no doubling of number if "modified" badge additionally gets a new name (something like _Treasure Hunter_ comes to mind) while old version respectfully retires with current name

Comment: Shog, out of curiosity, how would awarded redefined Reversals "intersect" with Explainer -> Refiner -> Illuminator badges? I guess there's a good chance that question score reverses because of edits and maybe some of these edits qualify for refinement badges - wonder how much this guess is reflected in stats

Comment: also wonder what would be _skeetness_ of a redefined badge. For comparison, Jon has [6 of current Reversals](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal?userid=22656)

Comment: I am not sure there should be symmetry in the question scores. If the point is to avoid encouraging answers to low quality questions, lets draw the line at -2. But I think that getting to +2 isn't much of a reversal. What would the numbers look like for `-2/+5`?

Comment: 414 badges, @Travis; results are pretty close to -2/+2.

Comment: @Shog9 - Okay, so I suppose the +2 versus +5 is inconsequential. I think the -2 should be the lower bounds though, questions with more than -2 votes probably include a lot of questions that shouldn't be answered. Although you probably know more than I do on that, just my opinion :)

Comment: That's why I published the full dataset, @TravisJ - you don't have to trust me, just take a look... It's actually rather eye-opening.

Comment: Ah I see, I made the false assumption the link only contained questions which got at worst to -1.

Comment: Skeet would end up with 3 new badges at +-3, @gnat. Only 3 other people would earn more than 1 new badge: brian d foy, Rohit Jain and Brad Larson would each earn 2. Note that we don't normally revoke badges even when criteria change, so no one would have *fewer* reversals.

Comment: 3 is not too far away from his current 6 - seems like a difficulty of a modified badge would be close to original one; I like that

Comment: The [Red Baron hat](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/red-baron) was inpired by this idea. I think -1/+1 is too easy to manipulate once there's an incentive to do so.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279285/can-we-retire-the-reversal-badge#comment904959_279285  it still encourages people to answer rubbish, I think it's best to avoid it and perhaps offer people a badge for a posts that undergo a reversal from -5 to a positive value generally

Comment: Shog any chance we can get a stamp either way on this as a feature request?

Comment: See update, @Yvette.

Comment: Needs update again

Answer (score -14):

What's the harm in trying? If someone can provide a good answer to a bad question, more power to them. If the question is so bad that it's merely taking up space and just reading the answers is a waste of time, then perhaps the question should be closed.

Comment: How often are people trying to provide good answers and not so much trying to game the badge?

Comment: @BoltClock the whole site is a game ;) I don't know, but I got the badge "organically"... on a question that's since been deleted.

Comment: getting a badge for answering a delete-worthy question is certainly "organic"... in the sense that this perfectly matches the idea that **[Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)**