# Did the Red Baron hat motivate you to be a better Stack Overflow user?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, winter-bash-2014, gamification

Note: This question was inspired by a hat but it's actually about your experience interacting with the site *in pursuit of* a hat.

During Winter Bash 2014, I spent a lot of time thinking about hats. In particular, **I gave a lot of thought to the Red Baron**. For reference, the requirement to earn this hat was:

> answer +5 a -3 question that goes to +3

According to the [Winter Bash wrap-up blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/), only 26 users earned the Red Baron across the entire network, making it quite a difficult reward to achieve. This had already become clear toward the end of the event, as the Leaderboard began to fill up with [aspiring Cubbinses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_500_Hats_of_Bartholomew_Cubbins), and it got me thinking: as the most difficult hat to earn, does the Red Baron represent an exceptionally high standard for contributions to the site? So I wanted to ask directly of those users who actively tried to earn the Red Baron: **Do you feel that your attempts to earn this hat made you a better user on Stack Overflow? Do you feel that you went above and beyond in order to curate an unappreciated or misunderstood question?**

Or, do you feel like you polished a turd? If you looked for questions at -2 or -3 to answer, did you find them all to be uninteresting, unhelpful or otherwise not worth answering? If so, did you answer them anyway, and try your best to polish and promote them, to turn them around?

There's always talk about whether some rewards encourage bad behavior (e.g., [The Sumo Judge hat is disruptive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245300/254929)). Actively pursing the Naruto hat late in this season's Bash left a bit of a bad taste in my mouth; I didn't even take a shot at Selfie because I didn't feel I had anything important to share, though I've had success with self-answers a few times in the past.

**If you didn't attempt to earn the Red Baron**, or if you tried, but without any particular strategy, or if you just didn't give much thought to the requirements themselves, [here's the question I chose as a likely candidate for earning the hat myself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27680107/2359271). the first revision was not very good but the author was responding to comments and trying to address them with edits; the basic level of OP investment required to turn the question around was there. Thanks to the particular experiences I've had, I felt able to see the diamond in the rough—the interesting, useful question hidden inside a somewhat broad and unclear problem statement. So here's what I did:

- I wrote up a detailed answer, aimed at the question I thought the author was trying to express.
- I left a comment on the question (now deleted) asking for OP's feedback on whether I had correctly interpreted their question.
- After OP accepted my answer and commented that it was useful, I [suggested an edit that aggressively reworked the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6615176) but focused more on clarity, directness and title/tags than actual content.
- After OP indicated again that I was on the right track, I put together a sample schema with example data that seemed to fit the question. [I ran this content by the OP again before doing anything with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680107/how-to-link-many-tables-containing-the-same-products-with-different-columns-and#comment43861316_27680107).
- With OP's approval, [I suggested another edit to incorporate the example I had created](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6633740) into the question. This was an even more aggressive edit than the first; I was replacing much of the OP's words and content, so I took pains to make my edit summary clear and detailed.

After all this, I put a 200-rep bounty on the question to try to give it a "second first impression" (and hopefully, to earn myself a hat). In the end, the question remains a little too broad and not quite clear enough to be top-notch, but I think I've taken it as far as I can as a third-party editor. I think it's unarguably a better question than it was but I still wonder: **Is this type of aggressive revision something we should aspire to accomplish—like earning a rare Winter Bash hat?** Or did I [go too far](http://dresdencodak.com/2009/09/22/caveman-science-fiction/)?

Comment: As an aside, it was my interpretation that the Red Baron hat was a bit of an experiment to see how a suggested change to the Reversal badge rules would go (since the method for getting it was awfully close to one of the suggestions).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That hadn't occurred to me. I'm looking forward to this year's winter bash wrap-up blog post, where that sort of thing might be discussed. (For the lazy and/or forgetful: ["Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal))

Comment: For reference, here is the suggestion from Shog: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277781/1783619

Comment: Forget everything, it doesn't do it already :D

Comment: For the record, I was looking for the candidates the enter Winter Bash but never found a suitable one. It's the only hat I didn't get :( But other than that, I didn't really do anything special to try to get it.

Comment: If I did that on every question I answered, I'd burn out in a week or two.

Comment: Related: [So long Winter Bash 2014](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/). I'll probably have more to write in the coming weeks as we take a look at how the hat was earned.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Dude, [that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277691/103167)'s not Shog's suggestion.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, it was your suggestion he was going off of, then tweaked a bit (which gets closer to what the hat was requiring). I mostly was indicating that I was linking to his post. Sorry for the mis-attribution.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Looks like [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/?cb=1) made exactly the same mistake :-p

Comment: @BenVoigt: I considered linking to your answer but Shog's fleshed out the idea in more detail. The credit is all yours.

Comment: @JonEricson: Yes, Shog did do a good job of recognizing the source.

Comment: It seems those hats had a strange effect on people, either good or bad. I am glad I was too busy eating holiday foods to notice them :P

Comment: It should be worth noting that there is at least one user who formed a voting ring to get the Red Baron.

Comment: What does "answer +5 a -3 question that goes to +3" mean in English?

Comment: @DavidConrad You must submit a new answer to a question when the question's net score is -3 (or lower), after which the question's net score must reach +3 (or higher) and your answer's net score must reach +5 (or higher).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I did not get the hat, but I can add a bit of data to the discussion. Here are the questions that earned Stack Overflow users their Red Barons:

- [What does "i" mean in a CSS attribute selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506735) (Alexander O'Mara)

  This is the example I highlighted in [my wrap-up post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/). I don't have much else to add to [Alex's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281882/1438).
- [C++ CodeBlocks disassembly; Way too much code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517471) (Jerry Coffin)

  The question had a rather [complicated history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27517471/revisions):

  - Dec 17 '14 at 2:34: asked
  - Dec 17 '14 at 2:36: first close vote (-1)
  - Dec 17 '14 at 2:39: [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27517518/1438)  (-2)
  - Dec 17 '14 at 2:55: [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27517616/1438) (-5/+1)
  - Dec 17 '14 at 3:05: [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6505202) (-6/+2)
  - Dec 19 '14 at 16:54: first reopen vote (-6/+2)
  - Dec 19 '14 at 18:16: [reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6533664) (-6/+2)

  Over the next few days, it got 11 straight upvotes. The top answer really turned the tide here, but it needed an assist from the reopen queue. The only edit was an added tag, which hardly changed the question asked. In my estimation, this is a great example of [optimizing for pearls](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).
- [Python descending order from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550785) (Martijn Pieters)

  Martijn used the edit-and-answer combo to turn an [unremarkable question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27550785/1) into something helpful to future Python programmers with a detailed answer.
- [Memory corruption error while using auto_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566507) (karlphillip)

  The initial downvotes seem to have been the result of the question using a deprecated API. After karlphillip's answer, the question gathered 7 straight upvotes.
- [Reading and appending to the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573677) (Gilles)

  Gilles' edit wasn't the difference maker here, in my estimation. Rather, the question seemed to be upvoted as a result of his fine answer giving general advice about modifying a file using C.
- [Style children elements based on the count within their parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641597) (Gaby aka G. Petrioli and Joseph Marikle)

  This question has the distinction of supplying two Red Barons, so no one answer can be said to have turned the tide. A critical assist came from [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27641597/revisions) to remove "Here's a fiddle for you to fill out: [http://jsfiddle.net/q7gk608y/"](http://jsfiddle.net/q7gk608y/%22). Obviously that rubbed a lot of people the wrong way.
- [How to link many tables containing the same products with different columns and IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680107) (AirThomas)

  And this is your Red Baron, which you already explained.

---

Now there are a few voting oddities that I noticed:

- Since the answerer's votes count, it was possible to find a question at -2, downvote it, answer the question, and upvote it later. While this didn't happen on SO, I believe it was even possible to take advantage of the [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80763/1438) to manipulate the votes; no question edit was required. Not a huge deal in the grand scheme of things, but it might be worth excluding the answer's votes from the calculation.
- I didn't see this with these questions, but I do know that there was some chatroom activity around potential Red Baron questions encouraging upvotes. It's sort of a more purposeful version of the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). We see this occasionally with other badges ("Oh, I'm *one vote* away from a Great Answer: ") and it's not a huge deal. But it would be easy to imagine a room coordinating to downvote and then upvote a question for the sake of badges.  That would be pretty annoying to the asker who gets jerked around for no real benefit to them.

Overall, however, I think this experiment went well. Certainly Stack Overflow got 8 fine answers that would not likely exist otherwise. I'm going to look through the Red Baron hats on other sites and, if I don't see any major problems, suggest we use this criteria for a gold badge. (Not yet sure if replacing Reversal is the right plan, however.)

Comment: Appreciate the follow up; here's a green check mark for tasty, tasty data.

Answer (score 73):

As one of the lucky few who earned a Red Baron hat, I can say that yes, I think the hat did motivate me to become a better Stack Overflow user. At first, I didn't use any particular strategy to try to earn the hat, nor did I expect I would be able to achieve it having never gotten +7 for any of my previous answers, for questions of any quality. However, with the Red Baron hat suggesting it was possible a good question could fall through the cracks, I decided I would carefully consider the potential of all questions I saw being down-voted, before following suit.

When I stumbled upon [the question I ended up being awarded the hat for answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506735/what-does-i-mean-in-a-css-attribute-selector/27507191), it had already received many down-votes. I clicked on it, expecting to find a poorly worded question that was nothing more than an inquiry on a typo in someone else's code. I thought I would simply vote to close it like everyone else, probably down-vote as well, then leave.

What I found however, was an interesting and completely valid question that talked about a new feature I was not previously aware of. Some research and a little experimentation later, I determined that the question was completely valid, and something I'm sure that I and many others would be curious of in the coming months.

The question could use some TLC for sure, so in addition to answering the question, I also edited the question to show exactly what the person was seeing and up-voted the question to counter one of the many down-votes it received.

Had I not stopped to carefully consider the question, I too may have down-voted and/or voted to close. This answer has since become my highest-voted answer on Stack Overflow. If that is any indication of being a better Stack Overflow user, then I definitely think the Red Baron hat helped me to get there.

Comment: That question is a brilliant example of something that's perfectly understandable if read *closely* (yes, even the initial revision), but was downvoted to hell by, I guess, people rolling their eyes at the bad grammar and spelling (presumably because OP is not a native/fluent English speaker).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I'm not sure it's safe to assume that; a lot of people know English just fine, but prefer to write in "txt-spk" because they don't care enough to put in the effort. Those not fluent in the language generally note that in their question; I think in this case it was just a general misunderstanding of Stack Exchange quality standards (as is common with new users) and the kind of questions that are allowed here. Subsequent edits made the question acceptable and, while I don't doubt the role of Alexander's answer in improving it, the question wasn't the best to start out with.

Comment: I don't really get how people could downvote that question. Even before being edited anyone who actually knows the answer surely could understand it. I'd go as far as saying, except for adding a screenshot, the other edits are _bad_. But then that's the point -> no one who knew the answer actually had the opportunity of seeing it. (It was downvoted because the answer requires some very obscure CSS knowledge. People that _know_ CSS saw it, did not understand it, and felt it _must_ be wrong).

Comment: @Sergiu _"anyone who actually knows the answer surely could understand it"_ - that has nothing to do with being a good question.

Comment: Sooo, what? A good question is one that anyone with google search skills can answer by copy-pasting the title? As far as I can tell no rule has been broken with the original question. The answer was not trivial either.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv No, that's a *bad* question.

Comment: Exactly my point.

Comment: @Sergiu all I'm reacting to is your statement _"anyone who actually knows the answer surely could understand it"_. If you **have to know the answer to understand a question**, which is what you're saying, it's most likely **not a good question**. A good question poses the problem in such a way that someone without knowing the exact answer from the top of their head, but who has at least some experience in the subject or knows how to Google, can do the research necessary to answer it. The [first revision of that question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27506735/1) was crap.

Comment: I agree that the first revision was crap. The problem statement was not good. After revision, the problem statement is good. This is separable from whether the underlying question is good.

Comment: @AstroCB 'Has anyone idea what is "i" in atribute selector?' -- Why would someone lazily using 'txt-speak' bother to quote a letter mention or write out anyone (as opposed to 'ne1' or the like)? "Has anyone idea" is pretty clearly the construction of a non-native speaker. It's perfectly understandable, but idiomatically stands out as something no native speaker would likely ever say.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That's certainly possible; my comment was directed in a general sense, as I see this excuse used in a lot of cases where it's not warranted.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I did not say you _have_ to know the answer. I did not know the answer but was able to come up with a google query that does not contain "case" or "insensitive" and took me to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671238/css-selector-case-insensitive-for-attributes#answer-26721521

Comment: @CodeCaster: But I honestly cannot see anything wrong with the first version of the question. Most people mistakenly thought it was gibberish because they did not take the time to understand it. That's plain wrong, alongside most "gramer fixes".

Comment: Very nice job, and just FYI: You were the very first user to earn this hat anywhere.

Comment: @AstroCB I know what you mean and in the general sense I agree with you. :)

Comment: @balpha Cool! Thanks for telling me, I had no idea!

Answer (score 11):

No hats motivated me to do anything, because I opted out of hats. Several times, because they seem to need to be shucked once per site. Hats are intended to be fun and avoid undesirable incentives; what's the point of closely tuning inventives for a two-week goof?

Comment: What's the point of even having a two week goof? Why *not* closely turn incentives so you can collect data on usage? Rewarding particular behaviors is *fundamental* to how StackExchange works. Why pass up the opportunity to experiment with it?

Comment: Maybe I spent too much time talking about the hat. The carrot itself is not important; the question is, what does the carrot lead to and why?

Comment: @AirThomas it leads to a pointless waste of time... and Unicorns

Comment: The blog mentioned that 2 of the hats were experiments for possible future badges.  One was a success and probably will become a badge, the other was not.

Comment: I like unicorns!

Answer (score 11):

No.

At first I thought hats were fun, but it became too confusing about what was acceptable fun and what was not allowed even though it was fun, and some of the hats clearly invoked bad behaviour - either in response to them, or in response to the actions they encouraged or advertised, so I opted out

Answer (score 7):

***Caveat: my hat wasn't on SO. But my answer really applies to most sites I am active on, SO included***.

Im my case, [earning Red Baron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76889/how-did-draco-apparate-within-hogwarts/76900#76900) did NOT in any way change how I operate. I found a question that my SME allowed writing up a decent answer for (it wasn't a perfect answer, but the best one possible given known information - a frequent occurrence on a "soft" site like SFF); and did a minor edit, which combined with a prior edit by someone else improved the question a bit <sup>[1]</sup>.

However, earning it reinforced my depressing impression *(expressed by the fact that I was 100% sure I would easily find a question to earn that hat on)* that certain SE sites are overran by negatively-minded people who don't bother thinking before criticizing a question as "unanswerable"/"bad" simply because those people can't imagine an answer; or down-vote perfectly good questions over minor cosmetic issues. I'm  happy to get the hat; yet extremely sad that I have been proven right by it.

---

> Do you feel that your attempts to earn this hat made you a better user on Stack Overflow?

**No.** I earned the hat on SFF, but I have done similar things before, as a matter of my normal *modus operandi*, on both SO and other sites.

> Do you feel that you went above and beyond in order to curate an unappreciated or misunderstood question?

No. I figured out 2 minor cosmetic issues with the question, one of which was already fixed by an edit prior to my arrival. My edits were truly **un**-epic.

> Or, do you feel like you polished a turd?

**No.** It was a pretty good question in its core, so not a turd. It required minor polishing.

> If you looked for questions at -2 or -3 to answer, did you find them all to be uninteresting, unhelpful or otherwise not worth answering?

Some were rubbish and unanswerabe. I was pretty sure I'd find at least one that was not, based on past experience, and was correct in my expectation.

> If so, did you answer them anyway, and try your best to polish and promote them, to turn them around?

I did not answer the rubbish ones. I downvoted them even further; and almost 100% of them were either already closed, or I VTCed them. We have very rare case on SFF of questions that are at -3 or below and NOT VTC-worthy.

---

P.S. I would like to add my "metoo" to the chorus of people noting that Naruto and Pizza hats were awful ideas that at best promoted bad behavior.

- I got Naruto basically by accident (found an obscure question from a new user that was mis-tagged with an obscure tag I was interested in; and thus not getting any attention); and **did not bother editing it to improve the tags** to avoid up-votes after answering.
- I posted a question that I knew was going to generate controversy to get a Pizza hat (and didn't even get it, for my troubles!). It was a not a bad question, just too general and underspecified specifically to attract a bit more answers than it otherwise would have. I felt so annoyed I decided to not try again.

---

<sub>[1] In this case, the question was percieved poorly to the tune of -3 simply because:</sub>

<sub>1. The user asked a movie-specific question - a very valid one - for something that didn't happen in a book, but didn't add "movie" tag to it.</sub>

<sub>2. the user didn't remember a minor detail from the movie (character name) and didn't bother doing 
detailed research on what the name was, considering the question had nothing to do with said character. As I noted in a comment, I - an acknowledged SME on the subject - didn't remember the character name off the bat either</sub>

<sub>3. It was a plot hole question with no clear explanation</sub>

Answer (score 4):

While I always enjoy the annual hat dash, and managed to get quite a few across many sites (think I came in 9th overall, and 1st on Information Security) this was one of 3 hats that I felt didn't really meet the spirit of 'demonstrating good behaviours' (the other two being Pizza and Naruto)

So while most of my hats were achieved through generally doing what I do every day: posting, editing and moderating, the Red Baron wasn't. It required finding a candidate question that in reality was not worth that 5 minutes effort, and a bit of rounding up some votes.

So this wouldn't be one I'd like to see next year.

Comment: In your opinion, was the CSS question used in the wrap-up blog post as an example of a Red Baron award not worth the effort, given the end result?

Comment: I hadn't read through it (CSS is not in my skillset at all) but it does seem like a good question and good answer. So my experience may not have been the same as everyone's.

Comment: What was wrong with Naruto? We have two *normal* badges with similar criteria. Pizza was a bit ridiculous.

Comment: Naruto criteria aren't that likely to happen on security, my main site