# Are the new badges mislabeled in our Help center?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, help-center

This [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) announced the new **Lifejacket** and **Lifeboat** badges and clearly labels them as *Answer Badges*. Also see [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386178/8239061).

However, in our [Help Center --> Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), the new badges are listed as *Question Badges*. Screenshot below.

Which is correct?

[image: Screenshot showing new badges as question badges]

Comment: Was just about to ask the same thing.

Comment: Meta dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329677/move-lifejacket-and-lifeboat-to-answer-badges-section-in-help-center

Comment: Beat by 15 min! Good catch @πάνταῥεῖ .  I didn't see that.

Comment: Well done! Here's a lifejacket for your efforts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be resolved now.
 Let the lifesaving continue.

[image: Image showing Lifejacket and Lifeboat badges correctly listed with Answer Badges]

Comment: You should know that here on meta people prefer free-hand circles: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/376604

Comment: For the sake of my legacy, it's free-hand circles from now on.