# Why didn't I get the Tumbleweed badge for a low-valued question?

Tags: support, badges, tumbleweed-badge

[How to search GitHub issues/PR's made by a GitHub App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820195/how-to-search-github-issues-prs-made-by-a-github-app) was posted a month ago with less than ten views, no answers and no votes.  (Votes induce rep change, so I would know in case of any.)  However, I didn't get the [tumbleweed](/questions/tagged/tumbleweed) badge.  ([my badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184351/gnusupporter-8964%E6%B0%91%E4%B8%BB%E5%A5%B3%E7%A5%9E-%E5%9C%B0%E4%B8%8B%E6%95%99%E6%9C%83?tab=badges&sort=recent)).

Could anybody explain the reason behind this?

Here's a snapshot on archive.org for reference: https://web.archive.org/web/20190802173424/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820195/how-to-search-github-issues-prs-made-by-a-github-app

Comment: There's no Tumbleweed badge anymore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/

Comment: The close reason is false, the problem can be easily reproduced: by asking a question keeping the Tumbleweed criteria, you won't get the badge. It is because this badge is removed. I vote to "leave open" (might be closed as dupe).

Comment: The closest thing to a “no more Tumbleweed” post we have on this Meta is [Data science time! June 2019 and the Tumbleweed badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386178). Probably not a good dupe target.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This badge is retired and is no longer awarded.
>   <sub>([source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed))</sub>