# The secret behind Reversal badge

Tags: discussion

[**Reversal**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badge has an information about `Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score.` I don't understand why `-5` score for? So we have to wait untill the question get 5 down-votes which is looks like so mean .

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277576/get-rid-of-the-reversal-badge/277691#277691

Comment: @Shog9 it's not just related, it's a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

If you think about it, it makes sense.  What you're doing is providing a stellar answer to a question that has already been knocked off of the front page and the community has already felt like isn't a very good question.

If you look at some of the [badge holders](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal), you'll see examples of the answers that earn them this sort of badge.

I wouldn't consider it "mean", per se - the question itself isn't all that great, but the emphasis is on the quality of answers instead.

That's why this badge makes sense to have at least -5 score on the question, and +20 on answer score.  The answer outshined a question that the community didn't feel was very good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701513/open-links-in-new-tabs/27701759#27701759  the `meta effect` huh

Comment: I never said that the Meta Effect didn't factor into this.

Comment: I never said you said Meta Effect didn't factor into this.

Comment: At least that's what one *hopes* happens for the badge. And there are actually some such pearls, though answers bashing completely incompetent,  off-topic and unethical questions are the majority... which is the reason most of them are deleted.