# Has this post been a victim of a serial down-voter?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes

It seems to me as though someone has come along to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335844/show-progress-bar-or-spinner-when-ajax-is-running) and down-voted all the answers.

I'm fairly certain it's not the OP because they don't have enough reputation so I'm confused as to why three genuinely decent answers (in my opinion) all got down-voted, especially as the thread basically died three days ago.

I'm *fairly* sure the other two answers to mine were down-voted at the same time (today). Perhaps one person got down-voted and they decided to down-vote all the other answers? Or even perhaps someone has been hacked and their hacker is going around down-voting posts to lose their reputation? Either way, to me it seems as though some dodgy down-voting has gone on.

Would the serial down-vote bot reverse this sort of behaviour if it is? I've only seen it mentioned that it reverses attacks on a specific person, rather than a specific post...

Comment: serial-downvoter usually refers to one user downvoting a lot of posts from a single poster, not all answers on a single question. So no the serial-voting reverse would not help here

Comment: It just looks like someone didn't think the quality of the posts where that good and two of the answers look like low quality ones at a quick glance.

Comment: TL;DR: No, Serial downvoting doesn't apply to posts; it applies to behavior towards a person.

Comment: The two short answers were downvoted quite close together in time, but this is normal if the same person thinks two short answers to a question are poor. Yours was downvoted about 20 minutes later. Maybe they're a slow reader, or more likely it was someone else for some reason which we'll never know.

Comment: @BillWoodger Strange, how do you see when things were voted on?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I thought that might be the case, that's not a problem, I'm not going to cry over one measly DV.

Comment: Look at the reputation list of the user (by post). It either shows the time directly, or you hover over the bit which says "5 hours ago". Same anywhere you see a date. Hover.

Comment: @BillWoodger I see that myself and `The F` had ours down-voted 10 seconds apart today about 9:38am. `Developer` had his down-voted on the 10th (3 days ago). Perhaps he came back to to his PC after the weekend and decided to bring the other answers down to his level... :/

Comment: None of the answers solve the problem, because with an `async: false` ajax request, it isn't possible to have a spinner.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not so sure about that. It's still a callback with a before and after point whether it's asynchronous or not?

Comment: Right, but, it can't spin because the browser is locked up. And, it won't show up unless you move the ajax call itself to a new callstack, again, because the browser will be locked up.

Comment: @KevinB I'm sure an animated gif doesn't care about JavaScript that's running?

Comment: The browser renderer does, it's gets ran by the event loop, which doesn't run until the callstack is clear.

Comment: @JamieBarker Although that scenario is a possibility, you really have nothing to indicate that it is so. As was mentioned earlier, they could be votes due to the question (answering a "bad" question) or by two different people at the same time, or by Santa Claus. You just can't tell. If you *knew for sure*  that the other user lost two rep, perhaps.

Comment: @JamieBarker It's clear by reading the question that the OP's previous attempts at solving this problem were caused by having `async: false`, so any valid answer to this question would need to point out that `async: false` is preventing the spinner from ever being rendered until after the ajax request is complete. *"The progress bar and spinner will only appear at same time with the success alert from ajax"*

Comment: @BillWoodger It was just a suggestion as to what it might be, rather like "_perhaps it will rain tomorrow_". It's a shame if it is and I wonder if there's a way to discourage it, aside from the -1 rep for a down-vote.

Comment: @KevinB That's great, (no, really). Perhaps you should post that as an answer to the question then? After all, it's not me that has that issue ;)

Comment: Interestingly enough the first dupe i found had an answer from me. :)

Comment: I don't see why this got so far. @KevinB is entirely correct, with the browser locking, any animation is going to be seriously hindered. The answer didn't address that and is probably why it was downvoted. I didn't downvote it, and am not going to due to meta effect reasons, but that is why I believe it occurred.

Comment: @gnat Isn't a post suppose to have answers to answer a question?

Comment: @Scratte the criteria you mention is only for main sites, at meta it is not required

Answer (score 16):

Some people object to answering bad questions. Such a person might downvote all of them. I don't think that this is officially discouraged. For the record, it wasn't me *this* time.

Comment: _I don't think that this is officially discouraged._ What about the [reversal badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal)?

Comment: @BSMP: I don't think downvoting people for trying to game the system by getting a bad for answering a bad question is officially discouraged, either.

Comment: @Wooble - How do you get the reversal badge without answering a bad question? Are SO users in the habit of giving good questions 5+ down votes?

Comment: You wouldn't. But it shouldn't be easy or risk-free to get. You'd better write a *really* good answer if you want to overcome the downvotes.

Comment: @Wooble list out the Reversal badge awards. More than half of the questions are `(post deleted or otherwise unavailable)`. This is a title of one `What does this mean? for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {`. If that is basically the entire question, it is difficult to imagine a stellar rather than plain popular answer.

Comment: @Wooble Indeed, looking at the latest two Reversal badges, they both came from the same question. Again of the type "how do I add one to a variable in language x". Gold if you can find the right question, and answer it.

Comment: I don't think this was the case. The answer was incorrect and that is probably why it received downvotes.

Comment: My apologies as [the discussion on the reversal badge happened months ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277576/get-rid-of-the-reversal-badge)

Comment: People can vote any way they want, but you should be voting the quality of the specific post. But I don't think you should be down-voting a good answer to a bad question purely because the question was bad.