# Can we retire the Reversal badge on SO, not meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts, badges

I'm re-posting this request,as it was last requested 18 months ago, had overwhelming support, yet it wasn't actioned and we can no longer place bounties on meta posts.

This question is posted on SE Meta [Can we retire the Reversal badge on main sites and keep it only for meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279285/can-we-retire-the-reversal-badge), I'm asking it here to make it specific to SO, as there is [some contention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279750/310756) with the smaller sites.

It was asked at the end of 2014 
[Get rid of the Reversal badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277576/get-rid-of-the-reversal-badge) with number of net upvotes 90 (114-24) at this posting.

The [Reversal badge](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal):

> Provide an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

There are multiple issues about discouraging [Fast Gun In The West (FGITW)](//meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=fgitw) and on [SO meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fgitw) and [answering low quality questions](//meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%20to%20low%20quality%20question)   and on [SO meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%20to%20low%20quality%20question).

Rewarding users for answering a question with minus 5 downvotes is usually encouraging this type of behaviour. The exception being when a question is downvoted for being off topic and then edited into a decent question. As evidenced by [The Lost Worlds of the Reversal Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88709/the-lost-worlds-of-the-reversal-badge), this is not the usual case — instead, more than half the questions are eventually deleted!

Can we archive the Reversal badge on SO, not meta?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279751/310756

Comment: The ideal solution here would be for us to just close more stuff faster... but that's probably not going to happen.

Comment: @Undo yes and just get rid of all incentive to answer.

Comment: Today in [socvr](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) we deleted 20 from java and 35 from python by focusing on heavily downvoted closed questions. Why do I mention this? Because people can arrive there  and request that others review closed questions (or those to be). As for badges, I don't know, what does that matter? I don't see someone having that as a motivation for FGITW behavior. Rather, they want rep mostly. No? Those badge owners doubled since bluefeet commented 2 years or so ago. Bring your requests to socvr is one idea.

Comment: @Drew: Given that the badge is often held up as a reason *not* to downvote answers to bad questions, the badge is indirectly a rep incentive as well as a badge incentive.

Comment: I haven't run into that "here comes another Reversal badge" comment but perhaps once. Perhaps I should go to sede and run a comment query. Maybe the thought is in the back of many people's minds as why not to downvote. I do know that I look at a ton of questions a day. And I often wonder on the horrible ones why there is often not even a single DV. Not more often than not, but just often. As if the world was asleep and down they get pushed.

Comment: @Drew I'd generally agree with you on badges not being a strong incentive, but then again we have buttload of robo-reviewers, and that can only be attributed to badges. I do wonder about those comments, though;)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: "*Given that the badge is often held up as a reason not to downvote answers to bad questions*" I thought the primary argument against doing that is that you're supposed to downvote based on the *quality* of the content, not for meta-reasons like whether it was posted on a bad question.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The usual counter-counter-argument is that answers to terrible questions are "not useful" because they're not searchable. In any case, that's a discussion worth having *without* the distraction of a site-sanctioned badge weighting one side heavier than the other.

Comment: @NathanTuggy well this Q is going no where vote wise, the original on SO meta has many upvotes. I don't know what else to do. Is there a way to kick the earlier question? Or has community consensus changed?

Comment: @Yvette: There's a known phenomenon of later requests for the same thing often getting much worse reception. It's not clear what anyone can do about it or how much to worry about it.

Answer (score -6):

I think this would be a good thing if it were to be removed. Although I am new I think that's a kinda not acceptable badge. So I agree with you completely.

Comment: If you're going to post an answer you should be supporting your position and explaining *why* you feel this action is merited, not merely stating your opinion without supporting it.

Comment: What do you think I was doing

Comment: That was supporting it by saying its a not acceptable badge!

Comment: That is nothing more than a statement of your opinion.