# Let's not be too trigger happy in deleting questions with good answers

Tags: discussion

Consider this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45141746/find-minimum-count-of-magic-numbers-to-get-a-sum

Yes the question is faulty but the highest voted answer is excellent; it has pedagogical value insofar that it teaches you to think round a problem. As such, it could be of benefit to the wider community and therefore in my opinion should be part of the Q & A knowledge base. It's also discouraging to folk supplying well thought-out answers if the page is closed off and subsequently deleted.

Given that the answer is analytic, it is hardly too broad.

I've voted to undelete along with, currently, one other person.

Comment: 130+ upvotes to request [Get rid of the Reversal badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277576/839601) suggest that many consider that it encourages unwanted behavior

Comment: An answer that can't be found due a faulty question isn't a good answer.

Comment: @Braiam: I disagree; the quality of an answer is independent of the quality of the question. But the presence of a good answer alone *cannot* justify the question that produced it. The question must justify itself.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, it's not.  The quality of an answer is quite intimately tied to the quality of the question.  Some answers are so good that they can still be useful *despite* the quality problems with the question (certain types of problems in the question are easier to overcome than others) resulting in an answer that's net useful, but the answer's quality *is* affected by the quality of the question.  A good answer is better when posted to a better question.

Comment: *Yes the question is faulty but the highest voted answer is excellent* - Anything for those of us under 10K so we can see it?

Comment: @BSMP Someone copy-pasted their homework assignment and someone told them how to do it.

Comment: @BSMP: I cast the third undelete vote, so you can see it for yourself. I don't like having questions deleted when there is an active discussion about whether they should be closed or not. Not sure how long it will last...

Comment: @user000001 That's asking for it to be undeleted, not reopened.

Comment: @user000001 Why vote to undelete a post that you don't think should be undeleted?

Comment: @NicolBolas if the answer can't be found, then the individual quality is not existent. Accessibility to the information is one of the dimensions of the quality of said information.

Comment: @user000001 So do you actually think that the post should be undeleted, or did you undelete it despite not thinking it should be undeleted just so people without the privilege to see deleted posts could see the post?  Either you undeleted it because you *actually* think it should be undeleted, or you undeleted it despite thinking that it shouldn't be undeleted.

Comment: @Servy: This really extensive comment discussion is getting distracting for the question, so I deleted my comments and added an answer with my thoughts, in case you are interested.

Comment: Aaaaaaand its gone

Comment: @user000001 If you actually think the post should be undeleted, then for future reference, I'd avoid saying that you're undeleting a post because you always undelete every post under discussion, regardless of whether it merits undeletion, and instead simply explain why you think the post merits undeletion.  It's more productive that way.

Comment: The post is already copy-pasted into enough sites, so I don't think it need to be un-deleted of SO (https://www.bing.com/search?q=There%20are%20magic%20numbers%20comprising%20of%20only%201%20and%200%2C%20such%20as%200%2C%201%2C%2010%2C%2011%2C%20100%2C%20101%2C%20110%2C%20111.....%20and%20so%20on.%20These%20are%20integer%20values%20and%20not%20binaries)..

Comment: It's because it's a mathematics question, not a coding question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[We seem to have a love-hate relationship with algorithm questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Balgorithm%5D+is%3Aq+score%3A10..+created%3A2016..)  On one hand, algorithm questions *are* [explicitly on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but there are a lot of us (myself included) that believe that some kind of "prior work" must be shown to us in order to make the question *good*.

The problem isn't that this question is bad or good - I don't really hold a strong opinion of either, but I *will* say that the answer made me give a bit of a standing ovation in its brilliance - but that **the community  hasn't really figured this kind of thing out yet.**  We like algorithm questions (kind of sort of), but we like them in a particular way.

Until we can say whether or not this question should *definitively* be deleted, closed, or stay open, we need to reach some kind of quorum on what we define algorithm questions as at all.  The link I put above (current as of 2016 onwards) has questions of varying quality and effort, and *all* of those have 10+ score.  If we want to effectively moderate these kinds of questions, we need to stop and think about what shape that moderation effort will actually take.

Comment: I think the main argument should be focusing in the other prong of the site topicness, namely "and is a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**"

Comment: @Braiam:  When I can eke out a bit of time, I'll ask a meta question of this matter.  It's gone on long enough that we've got several different thoughts on the matter that need to be coalesced.

Comment: Well, I'm just saying that the only thing that separates SO, from SU, CS, SF, SoftEng, etc. topic wise is actually that simple line.

Comment: Does the awesome [Waldo question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058) count (1602 upvotes for the accepted answer, though it is not tagged like that)?

Answer (score 6):

> As such, it could be of benefit to the wider community and therefore in my opinion should be part of the Q & A knowledge base.

That's the wrong criteria. SO cannot be a general clearing house of *everything* that "could be of benefit". By that logic, we should allow anyone to ask any sort of question, because it "could be of benefit" to someone.

SO has to maintain standards.

> It's also discouraging to folk supplying well thought-out answers if the page is closed off and subsequently deleted.

But it's not a good question for this site. It's not even particularly clear as to what it's talking about. We're *supposed* to discourage answers to poor questions, whether they're "well thought-out" or not.

> Answering downvoted questions is even to be encouraged! (Reversal badge).

I'm personally on the side of keeping the Reversal badge around. But every time someone like you comes along and suggests that the presence of this badge is *justification* for answering crap questions, that is merely another data point in favor of throwing it out. If it means people cannot come on MSO and declare that we secretly want bad questions so people can get the Reversal badge, then I have a hard time opposing getting rid of it.

Badges should not be thought of as encouragement. At least, not necessarily.

Comment: Just curious, why _do_ you support keeping the reversal badge around?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Well, in theory, it exists to reward answers that are *so good* that they were able to transcend being posted to a problematic question *and still be a valuable community asset anyway*.  The reality doesn't always live up to that however (or rather, the things people actually do in an attempt to get it don't necessarily live up to that).

Comment: @Bathsheba I actually read back through this post to find an instance of the four letter C-word I know to be profane (in the US, at least). Spoiler: I didn't find it.

Comment: @canon Took me a while.  Apparently I'm too old for this Crap.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: My reason for not wanting it removed is that it serves as kind of a consolation prize. Yeah, your answer is tied to a crap question, but you managed to rise above the crap and really deliver the goods. Remember: just because a question is downvoted doesn't mean it should be closed. It's a "fun" badge, like "tumbleweed", rather than a serious one.

Comment: So the use of the badge as "justification for answering crap questions" that you object to is referring to answering questions that should be closed rather than questions that should just be downvoted?

Comment: @Don'tPanic just as a curiosity: what prevents you from asking a good question and using the same answer?

Comment: @Braiam hmm? why do you ask me? I was just commenting because I was curious about Nicol Bolas's opinion on something in this answer.

Comment: @Don'tPanic for some reason, Nicol comment made me think that you were the one that posted the answer D: But anyways my comment apply to anyone disputing the deletion of the answer while recognizing that it was a crappy question.

Answer (score -9):

Here is a screenshot for the people with <10K rep: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZxTe.png)

I voted to undelete the question.

It may not be the best question, with the obvious lack of research effort, but the problem statement was crystal-clear, and it was interesting enough to generate a really good answer.

Keeping the question deleted, has two effects:

- It restores the reputation of the OP, and protects him from further downvotes.
- It wastes the effort of the person answering.

I think that we should be optimizing for pearls, for I voted to undelete.

Comment: The answer, given by a 200K rep user, is neither a pear nor a pearl. It's merely a hint, and says so in its first sentence.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Not all answers should be copy-paste ready. It gives the idea behind the algorithm.

Comment: I know it says it's just a hint, but "The highest digit in the target number is the answer" seems like more than just a hint.

Comment: I like how the OP asks for an "implementation algorithm" for that, though. That was great.

Comment: @user000001: An answer is not an answer if it doesn't answer the question. We don't want hints; we want *answers*. We want genuine, actionable information. This is one reason why answering such questions is wrong; it encourages making "hint" answers.