# Answer was downvoted - requesting advice for improvement

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I am having a hard time getting off the ground here, so-to-speak. I had previously asked a poorly received question, and so I deleted it.

Today, I tried my luck at posting [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52787457/9310072). I spent a good amount of time editing the author's question, and then again on my answer. And I was proud that it was soon upvoted.

With the +2 for the edit, and +10 for the answer, I achieved a new privilege (voting) and felt that I was on my way.

But then the answer was downvoted. No comment was left to provide any advice, and I lost my voting privilege.

I'm not complaining; the person had every right to downvote what he or she thought was a bad answer, but I really can't see where I might have improved it.

So, I am asking for advice on what constitutes a good answer. And more helpful, since it would provide me with a concrete example, would be to advise how I might improve my existing answer.

I have read all of the SO pages on writing questions/answers.

*PS: it may be instructive to note that I have just entered high-school this year, so I am new to nearly everything. But I work on programming every day, when I get home (they don't teach it yet.)*

*PPS: it cannot be just a coincidence that this morning my answer suddenly has lots of upvotes. I’m so excited! Thank you all. I hope my question here didn’t read as though I was soliciting upvotes.*

Comment: Something nitpicky - it *might* be because at first taste, the question you're answering appears to be too broad.  It could be the case that this is a perfectly common problem in Qt though; me not being an expert in it, I can only guess.  Otherwise I'm not really seeing much in the way of a problem with your direct answer.

Comment: @Makoto Thank you for the reply. But, shouldn't the question be downvoted instead in that case, and not an attempt to help the author. My father is teaching me programming (and we use Qt), so the question seemed fair to me, since I was only recently struggling with the same types of concerns. Again, thanks for the suggested reasoning.

Comment: It's a common pattern; questions which are off-topic usually produce answers which are off-topic so people often downvote them.  Again, not saying one way or another; just pointing out the rationale.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I understand that you are only offering an explanation, and I appreciate that. It does seem odd to me though. I thought I once saw a badge that was given for providing a good answer to a poor question, which would seem to suggest that doing so is encouraged.

Comment: And by my comment above, I don't mean to suggest that my answer was necessarily good (although I had thought/hoped it was). I was speaking in general terms.

Comment: Your answer is very ambitious.  Mentioning the concept of signals and slots is a good idea and solves the OP's problem, trying to explain it as well is not.  Very hard to do in the space of an SO answer box.  Do beware that you can't just blindly copy artwork.  It is has a GFDL license, I *think* that Stallman is trying to tell us explicitly that you can't copy it onto this site.  [Chapter 11](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/fdl.html).

Comment: @HansPassant I replied a little while ago (although, I replied as my Dad, since I didn’t realize that our computer was logged on as him). But he then told me that you may be right about the license. So, I deleted my reply. Anyway, I wanted to thank you for your comment and feedback! Anyway, he’s going to look into the potential licensing issue for me - which is way over my head.

Comment: re: your PPS: that's called the "meta effect": stuff linked to on meta tends to get a lot of votes.  If it's crap, it goes *way* down; voters coming from meta are more likely to have a critical eye than otherwise.  So the fact that you're getting upvotes is a good sign that experienced users think your answer is good.  This was a good meta question, and didn't come across as asking for votes at all.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Similar to what Makoto commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375277/answer-was-downvoted-requesting-advice-for-improvement?cb=1#comment637837_375277), people sometimes downvote good answers on low-quality questions.  I've definitely had good answers of mine downvoted, but almost exclusively on questions that also had downvotes.  So getting a downvote on an answer doesn't necessarily mean it's bad.

I think some voters are downvoting to discourage answerers from rewarding/encouraging lowish quality questions.

Other downvoters may be trying to make the question more easily / automatically deletable by not having any upvoted answers.  (This is [against the rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009/clean-up-by-downvoting-a-ridiculous-user-experience), BTW.  Please don't downvote good answers because of the question they're posted under, and definitely not *just* to allow automatic deletion of the question.)

---

> I thought I once saw a badge that was given for providing a good answer to a poor question, which would seem to suggest that doing so is encouraged.

Not really.  I think the point of the badge is to maybe encourage you to figure out what someone is really asking, and edit the downvoted question into something sensible and answer it.  Or maybe it was just an idea from way back in the early days of SO before the stream of questions grew to firehose level.  (The badge was added back in 2009, and it's not universally agreed to be a good idea exactly because it encourages "wasting" time on bad questions with low future value.  [Get rid of the Reversal badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277576/get-rid-of-the-reversal-badge))

It does still happen that there's a downvoted question worth answering, but in general no, better to just get them deleted and not clutter up SO with bad questions that are going to get in the way when future readers are searching for their problems.  SO is about building up a repository of good / useful Q&As, not just about solving the specific problem of each person that asked.  It wouldn't be worth putting nearly as much effort into answers if they were just for the one person asking.

I try to avoid answering lazy gimme the codez questions, but sometimes conceptual questions that are very confused get downvotes while there's still a kernel of an interesting question that I feel like answering.

Given my experience and rep on SO, I'm pretty confident in judging when my own answers are actually good, i.e. correct and hopefully helpful to someone who didn't already know the answer.  But still some of these have been downvoted.  It happens.  It's a lot easier to know you're right and shrug of a downvote that doesn't come with a correction in a comment when you have more rep.

---

I've found answers including examples with code to demonstrate a point are much more likely to get upvotes, because just explaining with words isn't enough for some people that are kind of lost and can't picture the code in their head.  e.g. [How do objects work in x86 at the assembly level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556511/how-do-objects-work-in-x86-at-the-assembly-level) has several tiny functions and the resulting compiler-generated asm to illustrate the points I was making.

IDK if that's relevant to the specific Q&A you were asking about in this meta question.  You have a diagram, but IDK if it would be practical to include any code to illustrate, or if it would take a very large amount of code to illustrate a big hierarchy.  I haven't designed a GUI in Qt, so I can't really evaluate the question or your answer myself.

Comment: This is very useful. I fully understand all of it, and hadn’t considered any of it. And while I was expecting answers such as “here’s what you did wrong” (since that was sort of what I had asked for), I feel much better with your “here’s what to look for before answering” approach. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the code examples: I see your point. It crossed my mind to try including some code, but I wasn’t sure that I could make the example concise enough (also it takes me an enormous amount of time to write code since I’m still learning it myself). I might have included some pseudo-code though. Thanks again.

Comment: @RhysFonville: code examples aren't always applicable, and sometimes not practical for large-scale software architecture things.  They're great for small-scale detail questions.

Comment: Even on some small-scale questions I've avoided writing code and instead described the *process* as its easy enough to write the code if you understand the steps (and I'm not always in a place to write code that compiles and runs flawlessly).

Comment: "Other downvoters may be trying to make the question more easily / automatically deletable by not having any upvoted answers." While voting is largely the prerogative of the individual, it's important to note that downvoting for this reason is expressly against the rules [per Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009/clean-up-by-downvoting-a-ridiculous-user-experience). Might be worth mentioning that in your answer.

Comment: @TylerH: thanks for the link, I'm glad there's an official rule against it.  Updated.

Comment: Also the badge idea that OP is talking about is the Reversal badge: "Provide an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score" itself added in around 2009 and not being immune to some criticism https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277576/get-rid-of-the-reversal-badge

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the particular answer is not one of quality but one of substance. It is not factually wrong, but that doesn't necessarily make it a good answer. Role encapsulation is the first thing people learn about OOP, and signals and slots is the first thing people learn about Qt.

Yes, historically SO wasn't an easy place to get off the ground if you are new to the site and to programming as a whole. As it seems tho, it is making a break neck transition to the other harmful end of the extremity.

Your answer isn't bad, but on its own, abstracted from other variables, it isn't good either. It is very basic, and all the information it contains has already been posted in countless answers, which the OP seems like never bothered to search, which is also a bad thing. Your answer is in line with someone your supposed age and level of experience, and it is also understandable that some people wouldn't know or care to give you special treatment because of your age. Which judging by the chronology of events is exactly what is happening in the opposite direction. When I saw this answer, I was really surprised, and my first thought was "voting fraud", because on its own, it doesn't really merit so much upvotes, but then I saw this post, and realized the votes came from people who seem to have gotten worried about your downvoting frustration and decided to give sort of a "participation award", which is their right, but I think may set a wrong level of expectations for you.

So the best advice I can give you to improve your answers in general is to acquire more knowledge to put in those answers, which takes years of experience. And don't get sidetracked with the reputation, a single downvote shouldn't be a drama worthy of a dedicated discussion. People often downvote just because, sometimes even excellent answers to complex questions. And don't expect that quality answers to complex questions will bring you more recognition or reputation, on the contrary, it is the popular, mediocre trivialities that bring the most repetition, and all those have been snagged by the early birds, while the complex answers to complex questions that bring a lot of knowledge with them tend to linger in obscurity, because the people who run into such things are few and far in between.

Comment: I really love your answer. The last paragraph, which I had to read several times, is my favorite. And, if I understand it correctly, it is where I want to be - writing the answers to the hard questions, which don’t bring much recognition because there are less people at that level. Regarding your advice to keep acquiring more knowledge - I literally work on this every day of my life. I read SO nonstop. I have read Martin’s “Clean Code” (which my father made me, though I admit that I’m glad he did), and I’m midway through a Qt 4 book now (Summerfield).

Comment: I understand what you mean about not getting sidetracked by reputation. The main reason I was worried was because: shortly after my question got a downvote, I tried to ask another, unrelated, question and SO popped up a scary message warning me that my account could be banned (or something) since my first, and only, question was deleted (by me, after it was downvoted several times) and my only answer was also downvoted. I decided against asking my coding question, and asked this meta question instead. That’s how this post came to be.

Comment: Yes, those "too many downvote" warnings could use a tune-down, and the sanctions often don't give people the necessary time to get accustomed, and definitely shouldn't be triggered by arbitrary downvoting. Good luck with programming, and keep in mind that like with most other skills, proficiency comes after at least 4-5 years of practice, so don't get ahead of yourself or easily discouraged.